# How to perform LEFT JOIN of a queried result with another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1` and `DE1_0_2008_BENEFICIARY_SUMMARY_FILE_SAMPLE_1` in the same database.

I have to perform a query on `DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1` and then perform the LEFT JOIN of this queried result with `DE1_0_2008_BENEFICIARY_SUMMARY_FILE_SAMPLE_1'. The query alone results in 1178 rows which is fine. But I am not able to do the LEFT JOIN. I used this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1` 
LEFT JOIN DE1_0_2008_BENEFICIARY_SUMMARY_FILE_SAMPLE_1 
ON DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1.DESYNPUF_ID = DE1_0_2008_BENEFICIARY_SUMMARY_FILE_SAMPLE_1.DESYNPUF_ID
WHERE DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1.ICD9_DGNS_CD_1 = 7243 OR DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1.ICD9_DGNS_CD_2 = 7243 OR DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1.ICD9_DGNS_CD_3 = 7243 OR ICD9_DGNS_CD_4 = 7243
```

Comment: Whats the error? When you say that you are "not able to do the LEFT JOIN"... why not? what's the issue?

Comment: Your query seems to ok

Comment: Whats the error. ??
Aren't you missing table_name at the last column_name in where clause.

Comment: As an aside, take a look at partitioning... and see normalization. Other than that, there's nothing wrong with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is technically fine.

Note that it can be rewritten more elegantly as follows, but really you need to take a closer look at both partitioning and, crucially, normalisation...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DE1_0_2008_TO_2010_OUTPATIENT_CLAIMS_SAMPLE_1 o 
  LEFT 
  JOIN DE1_0_2008_BENEFICIARY_SUMMARY_FILE_SAMPLE_1 b
    ON o.DESYNPUF_ID = b.DESYNPUF_ID
 WHERE 7243 IN(o.ICD9_DGNS_CD_1,o.ICD9_DGNS_CD_2,o.ICD9_DGNS_CD_3,o.ICD9_DGNS_CD_4);
```